# Nested write append of NetCDF in Python is safe?

Tags: python, netcdf

This code appears to work, i.e. yield a sound NetCDF file with all 3 variables "my", "oh_my", and "gosh":

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
with Dataset('test.nc', 'w') as nc_outer:
    x=nc_outer.createVariable("my", "f4", )
    x[:]=3.0
    with Dataset('test.nc', 'a') as nc_inner:
        y=nc_inner.createVariable("oh_my", "f4", )
        y[:]=3.14
    z=nc_outer.createVariable("gosh", "f4",)
    z[:]=6.28
```

I suspect this works because at the filesystem level, the handles `nc_outer` and `nc_inner` are bound to the same file ('test.nc'), and by nature of the inner append-mode. If the inner mode is switched to write, Python not surprisingly raises PermissionError.

Does anyone believe/know this is NOT safe?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may be: "It depends".

When I tried a more complex nesting, it failed. In that particular case:

The **outer block**:

- defined 2 instances 'A' & 'B' of NetCDF Dimension in the root Group '/'
- created a Group '/a' within which a 3rd Dimension 'C'.

The **inner block**:

- defined a NetCDF Group '/b'
- within '/b' attempted to reference Dimensions 'A' and 'B' in creating Variables.

Dimensions of parent groups are visible for reference in subgroups, but what happened is within the inner block, print statements indicated the existing Dimensions were 'A' and 'C' ('B' missing).